# What's php-fpm , and How to use it

Tags: php

I've read abit about it , but I have difficulty finding a good source of information. Do I just install php-fpm and it's done? Or will I have to change code changes in php, I'm confused about why it's so hard to find a reliable source of information. Am I searching it wrong?

And also is it a standart(best-practice)?

Comment: No, you don't have to change any PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

**What is PHP-FPM?**

According to the official article on PHP website

> FPM stands for FastCGI Process Manager FPM (FastCGI Process Manager)
> is an alternative PHP FastCGI implementation with some additional
> features (mostly) useful for heavy-loaded sites. [[Read more]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)

**How to use it?**

You can easily [search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=centos%207%20php-fpm%20install&rlz=1C1GCEA_enVN934VN934&oq=centos%207%20php-fpm%20in&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30l8.8503j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it really simple in the installation step and configuration step too.

**Do I just install php-fpm and it's done?**

Yes, you just need to install, start and it done, it can make PHP code run without any problem.

**Why php-fpm and why not php-cgi?**

> Confused to use PHP-CGI or PHP-FPM for your websites on your web
> server? We will share some information about PHP-CGI and PHP-FPM in
> [this article](https://www.basezap.com/difference-php-cgi-php-fpm/).